# Retrieve GrandChild collection from root parent

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have the following object graph:

Root ( Root_Id)
----Child (Child_Id,Root_Id)
-------GrandChild (GrandChild_Id, Child_Id)

And I want to bypass Child and return GrandChild collection  having a Root object. So far i have tried this:

```
var child_Ids = db.Root
                .SingleOrDefault( r => r.Root_Id == rootID )
                .Childs
                .Select( ch => new {  Child_Id = ch.Child_Id} ).ToArray();

 return db.GrandChilds.Where( gc => child_Ids.Contains( gc.Child_Id ) );
```

But that wont even compile with the following errors : 
1) IEnumerable does not contain a definition for Contains... 
2) Argument instance: can not convert from 'AnonymousType # 1 []' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable

How can i accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var child_Ids = db.Root
    .SingleOrDefault( r => r.Root_Id == rootID )
    .Childs
    .Select( ch => ch.Child_Id)
    .ToArray();

 return 
     from grandChild in db.GrandChild
         join child_id in child_Ids
         on child_id == grandChild.HandlingUnit_Id 
     select grandChild;
```

P.S: I am still a bit unsure about your goal but it looks like working approximation of your original solution

**EDIT:**

If your hierarchy and classes are something like:

```
public class Db
{
    public Db(IEnumerable<Root> roots)
        {  this.Roots = new List<Root>(roots); }

    public ICollection<Root> Roots { get; private set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public Root(IEnumerable<Child> children )
    { 
        this.Children = new List<Child>(children);
    }

    public ICollection<Child> Children { get; private set; }
}


public class Child
{
    public Child(Int32 childId, Int32 rootId, IEnumerable<GrandChild> grandChildren)
    {
        this.Child_Id = childId;
        this.Root_Id = rootId; 
        this.GrandChildren = new List<GrandChild>(grandChildren);
    }

    public Int32 Child_Id { get; private set; }
    public Int32 Root_Id { get; private set; }
    public ICollection<GrandChild> GrandChildren {get; private set;}
}

public class GrandChild
{
    public GrandChild (Int32 grandChildId, Int32 childId)
    { 
        this.GrandChild_Id = grandChildId; 
        this.Child_Id = childId; 
    }

    public Int32 GrandChild_Id {get; private set;}
    public Int32 Child_Id {get; private set;}
}
```

Then as it was already suggested by **AD.NET** you could try the [SelectMany](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method

```
        GrandChild gc1 = new GrandChild(1, 10);
        GrandChild gc2 = new GrandChild(2, 10);
        GrandChild gc3 = new GrandChild(3, 11);

        Child c1 = new Child(10, 100, new GrandChild[]{ gc1, gc2 });
        Child c2 = new Child(11, 100, new GrandChild[]{ gc3 });

        Root r1 = new Root(new Child[]{c1, c2});

        Db db = new Db(new Root[] { r1 });

        var rootGrandChildren = db
            .Roots
            .FirstOrDefault()
            .Children
            .SelectMany(child => child.GrandChildren);
```

In query syntax it will look like

```
    var rootGrandChildren = from child in db.Roots.FirstOrDefault().Children
                            from grandChild in child.GrandChildren
                            select grandChild;
```

**But** if your `Child` class does not know his GrandChildren and they(GrandChildren) are contained in Root:

```
public class Child
{
    public Child(Int32 childId, Int32 rootId)
    {
        this.Child_Id = childId;
        this.Root_Id = rootId; 
    }

    public Int32 Child_Id { get; private set; }
    public Int32 Root_Id { get; private set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public Root(IEnumerable<Child> children, IEnumerable<GrandChild> grandChildren )
    { 
        this.Children = new List<Child>(children);
        this.GrandChildren = new List<GrandChild>(grandChildren );
    }

    public ICollection<Child> Children { get; private set; }
    public ICollection<GrandChild> GrandChildren{ get; private set; }
}
```

you will have to use:

```
  Root r1 = new Root(new Child[]{c1, c2}, new GrandChild[]{gc1, gc2, gc3});

  Db db = new Db(new Root[] { r1 });


  Root root = db.Roots.FirstOrDefault();

  var rootGrandChildren = from child in root.Children
                              join grandChild in root.GrandChildren
                              on  child.Child_Id equals grandChild.Child_Id
                          select grandChild;
```

Comment: The goal is to get the collection of grandchilds having the root parent, i dont need child collection for my use case. I'll try yor sugestion and let you know.

Comment: But what is the gc.HandlingUnit_Id in your original example?

Comment: sorry must be, it was a typo. (return db.GrandChilds.Where( gc => child_Ids.Contains( gc.Child_Id ) );). I updated the question to reflect that

Answer (score 2):

```
             db.Root
            .SingleOrDefault( r => r.Root_Id == rootID )
            .Childs.SelectMany(ch=>ch.GrandChilds).Distinct()
```

Use the `.SelectMany` extension to get the grandchildren collection

Comment: What's the compilation error? The property name might be different